# Python .exe problem

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I created an executable version of my application succesfully. It is just a basic database related app. So it has a database and an icon file in the same directory called “data”.
When I try to add an entry to my database by using the .exe file, it gives an error such as “unable to open database file”. But there is no problem with the icon file in the same directory.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'c:\dev\ms-vc-runtime\*.*')),("data", glob('Veriler\*'))]

options = {
    'py2exe': {
        'dll_excludes': [
            'MSVCP90.dll'
        ]
    }
}

setup(windows=[{"script": "Nokta Ekleme.pyw","icon_resources":[(1,"Veriler\Alarko.ico")]}], options=options, data_files=data_files)
```

Ok guys. I found the solution. The target and the source directories for data files must have the same name. So I changed the "Veriler" to "data". Now everything is ok.

Comment: Could you share the code which adds entries to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Are your globs returning the files you expect? Try `print glob('Veriler\*')`. You may need to give the full directory path.

Another option is that the dlls necessary to work with your db have been left out.

I would recommend pyInstaller over py2exe any day of the week though - you may find there is good mileage in switching to that as it handles grabbing the necessary files, including dlls which may be your problem, far better than py2exe.

Comment: your globs returning the files you expect?

Comment: You have used a glob to get the files for py2exe. It is possible that one of the following is happening: **1** There's a problem with the glob itself not identifying the files you need it to, for example, it's starting from the wrong working directory. **2** py2exe doesn't handle globs here and you need to specify the files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My globs are returning the files I expect. They are already copied from "Veriler" to "data" directory succesfully after .exe creation.

And the part that adds an entry to my database:

```
        con = lite.connect('data\noktalar.sdb')
        cur = con.cursor()
        ad = self.tc1.GetValue()
        cihaz = self.tc2.GetValue()
        tip = self.nokta_tipleri[self.CB1.GetCurrentSelection()] 
        miktar = self.sp.GetValue()


        cur.execute('insert into noktalar values(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (ad, cihaz, tip, miktar))
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
```

Comment: Next time edit the original question. Each SO question (should) lead to answers, not clarifications, edits etc.

Comment: Better still... *this time*, edit the original question. StackOverflow <> Usenet.